# Web Audio API Delay sounds distored in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I'm using Web Audio API with javascript.

I create an oscillator, connect it to the volume (gainNode), connect it to a destination.

Ok. Nice.

I want a delay effect, I stick it between oscillator and volume.

Well, that doesn't work, I only hear the delay. Although, it is clean.

Ok, so I connect the osc to the delay to the volume, and the osc to the volume, then the volume to the destination.

Now it seems to be distorted.

I tried osc to delay to volume to destination, with osc to destination so there are two connections to the destination. That too is distorted.

That's on chrome.

In the little time I've had to try it, it seems to work right on iOS6. Don't know about safari.

Try it by going to http://cloudmusiccompany.appspot.com/watch.jsp and clicking red and drawing. That's a normal sine osc. Now click white and draw, that is the same withing with the delay, and on chrome (Ubuntu) it is distorted. Don't know about Safar.

Obviously you can see the full source at the link because its javascript.

Relevant source:

```
function makeNewChannel(color){
  var info = getInstrumentInfo(color);
  var chan = {osc: acontext.createOscillator(),
    freqs: [],
    times: [],
    pxdata: [],
    i: 0,
    muted: true,
    finishedLoop: false, 
    volume: acontext.createGainNode(), 
    gate: acontext.createGainNode(), 
    delay: acontext.createDelayNode(),
    delayGain: acontext.createGainNode(), 
    mute: function(){
      this.muted = true;
      this.volume.gain.value = 0;
    },
    unmute: function(){
      this.muted = false;
      this.volume.gain.value = player.defaultGain / (info.soft ? 2 : 1);
    }
  }
  chan.osc.type = info.type;

  //        chan.osc.connect(chan.gate);
  chan.osc.connect(chan.volume);

  chan.delayGain.gain.value = player.defaultGain ;
  /* ugh , the wet sounds ok, but somehow its distorting or doubling the dry signal
   * although it seems ok on iphone?
   * */
  if (info.delay){
    chan.delay.delayTime.value = 0.5;
    chan.volume.connect(chan.delay)
    chan.delay.connect(chan.delayGain);

    chan.delayGain.connect(acontext.destination);

  }
  chan.volume.gain.value = 0; //player.defaultGain;
  chan.gate.gain.value = 0;
  chan.volume.connect(acontext.destination);
  chan.osc.frequency.value = 0;

  chan.osc.noteOn(0);
  return chan;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind extracting the routing from the source? It's a bit much to read through to find it..

Comment: Sorry, I've just been posting from my phone so I will try when I get on a computer. The relevant method is makeNewChannel

Comment: I think maybe if someone with an iOS6 device can confirm that is has a clear delay and chrome has a distorted one (by drawing with the color white at the web page above) that might indicate something. And Safari 6. Sorry, I know I should test on all platforms myself, I just don't have access to a Mac.

Comment: So you want to play the original oscillator sound, and then play it again delayed?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking like a delay pedal that a guitar player would use. And like I said, I'm pretty sure that iOS 6 gives the right result, where Chrome (on Ubuntu) distorts the sound. I don't have an iOS or Mac or Windows to test any better (I'm lame, I know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had a chance to use it on Chrome on Windows, and it works fine. Delay sounds like it should.

This must be a bug in the Linux version (of chrome)

Answer (score 1):

You could probably solve this by adding a compressor right before the context destination. All paths should connect to it, and then the compressor connects to the destination.

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#DynamicsCompressorNode

Comment: I had attempted that, specifically because the doc used it, and I used the same g1, s1 scheme too. But same effect. And whether its a compressor or gain at the end I wouldn't expect them to act too different. I even tried a channelSplitter and Merger though obviously they serve a different purpose.